# Incrementing value and setting it as var to onClick event

Tags: reactjs

I am facing a really odd problem which causes feel like "whatever you cal"

First of all here is the code:

```
renderImages = () => {
    let i = 0;
    const arr = [
        "https://truffle-assets.imgix.net/pxqrocxwsjcc_6OcJeUMaWIYOmKgsK6IwWc_galaxy-cupcakes_squareThumbnail_en-US.jpeg",
        "https://sallysbakingaddiction.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/moist-chocolate-cupcakes-5.jpg",
        "http://is4.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple127/v4/74/47/31/7447317e-9844-3ee0-d189-661a55c94abe/source/1200x630bb.jpg",
        "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/55/03/94/550394c428e268868aa73e509302b84c--neopolitan-cupcakes-ice-cream-cupcakes.jpg"
    ];

    return arr.map((item) => {
        i++;
        return(
            <div>
                <img src={item} onClick={() => alert(i)} alt={i} />
            </div>
        );
    })
};
```

Now when i click on an image, it always shows 4. First image shows 4 and last image shows 4. All of them alerts 4. However, their alt tag seems correct. I don't think i am doing something wrong but i am :)

My react version is 16.1.1

So anyone know what am i doing wrong here? I don't think it is a bind problem but who knows.

Comment: Use `map(item, index)` and `<img src={item} onClick={() => alert(index)} alt={index} />`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript's scopes are function-level, not block-level, and creating a closure just means that the enclosing scope gets added to the lexical environment of the enclosed function.

After the loop terminates, the function-level variable i has the value 4, and that's what the inner function 'sees'.

Now even though `let` has a block scope the scope of it is limited to the `renderImages` function and not the `map` and hence you still have a closure issue.

However `map` provides you the `second argument` as an `index`, which you can use instead of incrementing the variable and using it
like

```
renderImages = () => {
    const arr = [
        "https://truffle-assets.imgix.net/pxqrocxwsjcc_6OcJeUMaWIYOmKgsK6IwWc_galaxy-cupcakes_squareThumbnail_en-US.jpeg",
        "https://sallysbakingaddiction.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/moist-chocolate-cupcakes-5.jpg",
        "http://is4.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple127/v4/74/47/31/7447317e-9844-3ee0-d189-661a55c94abe/source/1200x630bb.jpg",
        "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/55/03/94/550394c428e268868aa73e509302b84c--neopolitan-cupcakes-ice-cream-cupcakes.jpg"
    ];

    return arr.map((item, index) => {
        return(
            <div>
                <img src={item} onClick={() => alert(index)} alt={index} />
            </div>
        );
    })
};
```

Here is how you can do it for nested arrays

```js
const arr = [[
        "https://truffle-assets.imgix.net/pxqrocxwsjcc_6OcJeUMaWIYOmKgsK6IwWc_galaxy-cupcakes_squareThumbnail_en-US.jpeg",
        "https://sallysbakingaddiction.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/moist-chocolate-cupcakes-5.jpg",
        "http://is4.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple127/v4/74/47/31/7447317e-9844-3ee0-d189-661a55c94abe/source/1200x630bb.jpg",
        "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/55/03/94/550394c428e268868aa73e509302b84c--neopolitan-cupcakes-ice-cream-cupcakes.jpg"
    ],[
        "https://truffle-assets.imgix.net/pxqrocxwsjcc_6OcJeUMaWIYOmKgsK6IwWc_galaxy-cupcakes_squareThumbnail_en-US.jpeg",
        "https://sallysbakingaddiction.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/moist-chocolate-cupcakes-5.jpg",
        "http://is4.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple127/v4/74/47/31/7447317e-9844-3ee0-d189-661a55c94abe/source/1200x630bb.jpg",
        "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/55/03/94/550394c428e268868aa73e509302b84c--neopolitan-cupcakes-ice-cream-cupcakes.jpg"
    ]];
    
const renderImages = (arr, idx) => {
    return arr.map((item, index) => {

        return(
            <div>
                <img src={item} onClick={() => alert(idx + index)} alt={idx + index} />
            </div>
        );
    })
};
const App = () => {
    let i = 0;
    
    return (
        <div>{arr.map((array, index) => {
            const val = renderImages(array, i);
            i += array.length;
            return <div>{val}</div>
        })}</div>
    )
}



ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"/>
```

Comment: my code block is a bit big and i have posted this example. Actually my map function is inside anıther map function. Array is chunked. That's why it becomes 1-2-3-4 and for the next row again it becomes 1-2-3-4. And from the parent map i also have index but adding them together does not do the trick

Comment: Don't understand why OP can't work this way, but +1 for superb explanation

Comment: Check out the snippet. It shows how you can work it out with nested maps

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what i was trying to findout. One last question, isn't it possible to do this in one function scope?

Comment: Will think about it and let you know if I come up with another solution

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your code the following way:

```
return arr.map((item, index) => {

        return(
            <div>
                <img src={item} onClick={() => alert(index)} alt={index} />
            </div>
        );
    })
```

That way you could remove `i` completely. Also keep in mind that the index is zero-based so you would maybe want to increment it with 1.

Comment: This works but i am trying to find a way to make it work in my way.