# React OnClick for item not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component which renders a list item with individual OnClick.

In order to find out which item was clicked, the handler accepts a parameter. The handler does get invoked - but no matter which item is clicked - console always logs item3 (as if item3 is clicked). What am I doing wrong here?

```
class Item {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onItemClickHandler = this.onItemClickHandler.bind(this)
    }

    onItemClickHandler (itemName) {
        console.log("Clicked " + itemName)
    }

    render() {
        this.items = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
        var lis = []
        for (var liName in this.items) {
            var liName2 = this.items[liName]
            console.log("Adding " + this.items[liName])
            lis.push(<li className="item-ListItem" key={this.items[liName]} onClick={() => this.onItemClickHandler(this.items[liName])}><span><a href="#">{this.items[liName]}</a></span></li>)
        }

        return (
          <div className="item">
            <label className="item-Header"><u>items</u></label>
            <ul className="item-List"> 
            {lis}
            </ul>

          </div>
        );
    }
```

This line:

```
onClick={() => this.onItemClickHandler(this.items[liName])}>
```

appears to be correct.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47395368/incrementing-value-and-setting-it-as-var-to-onclick-event/47395454#47395454

Comment: You are using `var` in that for loop. Use `let` keyword instead. Scope issues with var. See : https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20&%20closures/README.md

Comment: Using let solved the issue and was the most minimal change in my current code. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that you are not capturing the value of `this.items[liName]` correctly because by the time you reach the third item iteration the `onClick` handler will always have the value of `this.items[liName]` set to the third item.

The solution for that is using closure to capture the value correctly, i edited your code and created a fully working example in this link

https://codesandbox.io/s/3xrp6k9yvp

Also the example code is written below with the solution

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onItemClickHandler = this.onItemClickHandler.bind(this);
  }

  onItemClickHandler(itemName) {
    console.log("Clicked " + itemName);
  }

  render() {
    this.items = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];
    var lis = [];
    for (var liName in this.items) {
      var liName2 = this.items[liName];
      console.log("Adding " + this.items[liName]);

      //the clickHandler function here is the solution we created a function that get executed immediately each iteration and return a new function that has the correct value of `this.items[liName]` saved
      var clickHandler = (item => {
        return event => {
          this.onItemClickHandler(item);
        };
      })(this.items[liName]);

      lis.push(
        <li
          className="item-ListItem"
          key={this.items[liName]}
          onClick={clickHandler} // here we use the clickHandler function directly
        >
          <span>
            <a href="#">{this.items[liName]}</a>
          </span>
        </li>
      );
    }

    return (
      <div className="item">
        <label className="item-Header">
          <u>items</u>
        </label>
        <ul className="item-List">{lis}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

For more info and examples about closures check this [link](https://github.com/amrlabib/javascript-essentials-how-why/blob/master/closure.md)

---

**Edit** We can use `let` in ES6 instead of `var` in our for loop as mentioned by @ArchNoob because using `let` will make the `liName` block scoped

Comment: Thanks - personally prefer the code by stack26 below - as it does not use var clickHandler - but I assume that you did that for clarity - if I was just referring to stack26's code by itself - I think I would have been confused.

Comment: You are welcome ... glad it helped  :) ... yes its better to use immediately invoked function without using variables ... but as you said in the current situation it was going to be confusing placing it all inside the handler directly

Answer (score 2):

Please take care of indentation while posting the code. Its very difficult to understand without that. You have to make use of closure. whenever the loop gets over liName variable gets set to last index as scope chain will keep the liName value to last one. The solution is not make  a new scope between handler and click handler function where it is callled.
Here is the solution:

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.onItemClickHandler =             
    this.onItemClickHandler.bind(this)
  }

  onItemClickHandler(itemName) {
    debugger
   console.log("Clicked " + itemName)
  }
  
  render() {
    this.items = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
    var lis = []
    for (var liName in this.items) {
      var liName2 = this.items[liName]
      console.log("Adding " + this.items[liName])
      debugger
      lis.push( <li className = "item-ListItem"
                  key = {
                    this.items[liName]
                  }
                  onClick = {
                    ((item) => {
                      return () => this.onItemClickHandler(item)
                    })(this.items[liName])
                  }
                 >
                  <span>
                    <a href = "#"> {this.items[liName]} </a>
                  </span> 
                </li>
      )
    }
    
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="item">
        <label className="item-Header">
         <u>items</u>
        </label>
        <ul className="item-List" >
          {lis}
        </ul>
      </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will do it the recommended way.
First make a separate component of list-item.
To render list in react Js

```
//Handler
clickHandler=(id)=>{
    console.log(`Clicked on Item with Id ${id}`);
}

//render method
render(){
  let items = null;
  if(this.state.isAnyItem){
   <div className="items-list">
      {
        this.state.items.map((item)=>{
          <Item key={item.id} item={item} click={(item.id)=>this.clickHandler(item.id)}/>
         })
       }
   </div>
  }

return (
   <div>
     {/*Some JSX here*/}
        {items}
    </div>
  )
}
```

And Now the Item Component like

```
<div onClick={props.click}>
    {/*Some JSX Here*/}
    <h3>{item.name}</h3>
</div>
```