# ReactJS: onClick() sorting for dynamically rendered <th> elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, addeventlistener

I am printing the data fetched from an API into a table, and I am facing some difficulties to sort the column values, alphabetically and numerically. If the columns data within the API consists of numerical values, i.e. **`10.01, 333.01, 8.99 or 100.88`**, etc. to sort it ascending from **`0 -> 100`** on first click and on the second click descending **`100 -> 0`** and in the same logic for alphabetically values, i.e **`a-z && Z-A`** and reverse versa.

The function that I am familiar with **`onclick="sortTable(0)"`**, doesn't function in the same way in React, as I used to code it in javaScript. Probably I am misleading the ES6 standard, but I am not sure.

[image: Here is how it's look like my table without sorting functionality.]

Here is my code sample with **`onclick="sortTable(0)"`**, but it's doesn't function well:

```
class App extends React.Component
{
    constructor()
    {
        super();
        this.state = {
            rows: [],
            columns: [],
            clicked: false
        }

        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind( this );
    }

    handleClick()
    {
        this.setState( {
            clicked: true
        } );
    }


     sortTable( n )
{
            var table, columns, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
            table = document.getElementById( "datagrid" );
            switching = true;
            //Set the sorting direction to ascending:
            dir = "asc";
            /*Make a loop that will continue until
            no switching has been done:*/
            while ( switching )
            {
                //start by saying: no switching is done:
                switching = false;
                columns = table.getElementsByTagName( "TH" );
                /*Loop through all table rows (except the
                first, which contains table headers):*/
                for ( i = 1; i < ( columns.length - 1 ); i++ )
                {
                    //start by saying there should be no switching:
                    shouldSwitch = false;
                    /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
                    one from current row and one from the next:*/
                    x = columns[i].getElementsByTagName( "TH" )[n];
                    y = columns[i + 1].getElementsByTagName( "TH" )[n];
                    /*check if the two rows should switch place,
                    based on the direction, asc or desc:*/
                    if ( dir == "asc" )
                    {
                        if ( x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase() )
                        {
                            //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
                            shouldSwitch = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    } else if ( dir == "desc" )
                    {
                        if ( x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase() )
                        {
                            //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
                            shouldSwitch = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if ( shouldSwitch )
                {
                    /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
                    and mark that a switch has been done:*/
                    rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore( rows[i + 1], rows[i] );
                    switching = true;
                    //Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
                    switchcount++;
                } else
                {
                    /*If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
                    set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again.*/
                    if ( switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc" )
                    {
                        dir = "desc";
                        switching = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    componentDidMount()
    {

        fetch( "http://ickata.net/sag/api/staff/bonuses/" )
            .then( function ( response )
            {
                return response.json();
            } )
            .then( data =>
            {
                this.setState( { rows: data.rows, columns: data.columns } );
            } );

    }

    render()
    {

        return (
            <div id="container" className="container">
                <h1>Final Table with React JS</h1>
                <table className="datagrid">
                    <thead>
                        <tr> {
                            this.state.columns.map(( column, index ) =>
                            {
                                return ( <th onClick={this.handleClick}>{column}</th> )
                            }
                            )
                        }
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody> {
                        this.state.rows.map( row => (
                            <tr>{row.map( cell => (
                                <td>{typeof cell === 'number' ? cell.toFixed( 2 ) : cell}</td>
                            ) )}
                            </tr>
                        ) )
                    }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


ReactDOM.render( <div id="container"><App /></div>, document.querySelector( 'body' ) );
```

You are welcome to contribute directly to my Repo: [Fetching API data into a table](https://github.com/andimit/fetching-react-api)

My example, right after the **`onclick="sortTable(0)"`** has been used, doesn't htow any errors in the console, but it prints the same result. I guess I am not handling correct the **`<th onClick={this.handleClick}>{column}</th>`** elements.

[image: onClick event doesn't dunction]

Unfortunately I was not able to find related documentation at [ReactJs.org](https://reactjs.org/)

It's doesn't function the onClick event at all, so that I can't debug the sor functionality either.

Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where your code actually calls the `sortTable` method, but I believe there is a larger issue here.

You shouldn't be doing DOM manipulation manually unless you have a very good reason to. Instead, rely on React to manipulate the DOM, it's why you are using it. You are responsible for describing a Component's display based on its internal `state` and its `props`, which is what the `render()` function should reflect. In your case, the order of the rows would depend on the current sort column and the direction of the sort. So, you could add additional state for `sort`, which might be an object that includes the `column` to sort and `direction` of the sort. Whenever a column is clicked, you update `sort`, which will cause your component to re-render. Then, your `render()` function would take the current `sort` state into consideration when displaying the rows.

So to render the rows, you might write:

```
renderRows() {
  const sortFn = getSortFunction(this.state.sort); // defined elsewhere

  // shallow copy so we don't mutate the state
  return [ ...this.state.rows ]
    .sort(sortFn)
    .map((row, i) => (
      <tr key={i}>
        { row.map((cell, j) => <td key={j}>{ cell }</td>) }
      </tr>
    ));
}

render() {
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>{ renderHeader() }</thead>
      <tbody>{ renderRows() }</tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

Also, when rendering a React app, the `ReactDOM.render()` call replaces the content of the DOM element with the React element you provide. It is common practice to have a `<div id="root">` used as the app container, then replace its content with your app.

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but your suggestion doesn't function, because you don't define anywhere **`renderHeader`**. The rendering is not working with your statement, because I have to render the body between the `<dev>` elements, otherwise simply don't print anything, and instead of `root` my `id` is `container`. `ReactDOM.render( <div id="container"><App /></div>, document.querySelector( 'body' ) );`

Comment: It wasn't meant to be copied and pasted. If you don't understand how the `getSortFunction` and `renderHeader` functions should be implemented, I can help guide you after you put in some effort. Also, you can change the jsx in `render()` to reflect your needs, I was just providing an example.

Answer (score 0):

onClick = () => this.sortable(0). If you are using any kind of loop in that case you have to pass index to another function to pass through correct value of index. see this link for explanation
[React OnClick for item not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605783/react-onclick-for-item-not-working/47606231#47606231)

Comment: Hello @stack26 thank you for the answer, but I don't think this is relevant to my case. First we have here separate arrays: columns and rows, the description above I am stating that I want to handle the sorting funtionality of the rows values, through onClick event through the columns header elements.